# Drag & Resize images in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drag-and-drop, resize

Hello I want to drag image from another view and add that in another View and I am using SPUserRezisableView for resizing the view but it works only for UIView, how can I implement it for UIImageView.

Comment: same as we use in SPUserResizableView, with holding its corners.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link below for resizing the images in iphone.

[Resize Image High Quality](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5204-resize-image-high-quality.html)

I hope this will provide some help to solve the problem up

Comment: Thanx for the answer but I want to resize my image on stretching its corner at run time after adding it on UIImageView